# Why is my JavaScript code being rendered in the browser?

Tags: javascript, localhost

[image: The local host is loading the whole JS code]

I am new to programming and just started learning JS programming. I am confused as my localhost is showing the whole JavaScript code.

I have Node installed in my system. In VSCode, there is a button 'go live' and after writing and saving the code, when I run it and press the 'go live' button it redirects me to the browser. Then it displays the Js file instead of the print statement.

Comment: This looks like a Node server application. What happens if you load http://localhost:5500? How are you running it - what command do you use?

Comment: Yes, I have node installed in my system.  In VSCode, there is a button 'go live' and after writing and saving the code, when I run it and press the 'go live button it redirects me to the browser. then it displays the Js file instead of the print statement... I mean "hello!..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Go Live' feature from VSCode is for serving static Website files not for running your node.js server. So your javascript file will be served as a static file.

You can run it correctly using a terminal. In VSCode you can start an integrated terminal. Once you opened it type: `node FirstWeb.js` to start your server.